# What is the answer to this P&C problem.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

What is the answer to the below mentioned P&C problem:

> BurgerTown offers many options for customizing a burger. There are 3 types of meats and 7 condiments: lettuce,
>   tomatoes, pickles, onions, ketchup, mustard, and special sauce. A burger must include meat, but may include as
>   many or as few condiments as the customer wants. How many different burgers are possible?
>
> $(A) \ 8!$
>
> $(B) \ (3)(7!)$
>
> $(C) \ (3)(8!)$
>
> $(D) \ (8)(2^7)$
>
> $(E) \ (3)(2^7)$

I doubt the given answer, to just want to proofread.

Comment: What is the given answer ?

Comment: Theoretically this could be infinity as there is no contraint how many meats   you could have

Comment: There are 3 types of meats, right?

Comment: I could have 10000 of the same type of meat

Comment: If you doubt the given answer, you should explain what yours is and the reasoning behind it.  I can justify one of the choices, but can also argue all the choices are wrong, depending on the reading of the problem.

Comment: yes there are 3 type of meat.

Comment: @endlessProgrammer, what is the given answer?

Comment: @sandstone yes you can have any number of a kind of meat, but making the burger with 10 or 20  meat slices of the same kind will make it the same kind of burger.

Comment: its not C. I will like to give others a chance before revealing the answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan I have explained what I think about this problem

Comment: So this is the answer and the explanation, and I agree that the question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: (E). This problem tests the fundamental counting principle, which states that the total number of choices is equal
to the product of the independent choices. The key to this problem is realizing how many choices there are for each
option. For the meat, there are obviously 3 choices. For each of the condiments there are exactly 2 choices: yes or no.
The only real choice regarding each condiment is whether to include it at all. As there are 7 condiments, the total
number of choices is (3)(2)(2)(2)(2)(2)(2)(2) = (3)(2^7).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left({3 \choose 1}+ {3 \choose 2}+{3 \choose 3}\right)$ different choices for meats in the burger.

Then for the $7$ condiments we either have it or we dont

So I make it $\left({3 \choose 1}+ {3 \choose 2}+{3 \choose 3}\right) $$  \times 2^7$ which is not an answer

Comment: It must be assumed that we can have only one type of meat per burger, which would make it e)

Comment: If you mean your comment, there are only three choices for the meat.  If we are allowed multiple meats, I believe the order would not matter.  That makes none of the choices correct.  I don't think the problem is clear whether multiple meats are allowed.

Comment: why the meat choices are 3! and not 3C1 + 3C2 + 3C3 ?

Comment: @endlessProgrammer:  If we are allowed more than one meat, I agree with you.  Another way to get there is $2^3-1$, where each meat is yes/no but all no is the -1 deduction

Comment: Sorry my mistake

Comment: yes, I too agree this should be the answer.

Comment: You agree now that is

Comment: Even if you can have multiple meats, their order is irrelevant, and it is the number of meats that matter. You have 3 ways to have 1 meat. 3 ways to have two meats. 1 way to have all of them. This is 7 choices for meats, not 6.

Comment: @sandstone yes, I believe this should be the answer 7.2^7

Comment: Thats what I wrote? Put the combinations into a calculator

Comment: @sandstone Yeah sure, I am in complete agreement with you.

Comment: @sandstone  While your final answer is correct, the first sentence is not true.  The number of choices for meats is not $3!$.

Answer (score 3):

The question is *very slightly* ambiguous in my opinion, because the wording would suggest that one, two or three kinds of meat may be on the same burger but none of the supplied answers allow for this.

Under the assumption that each burger has one kind of meat on it, the answer is E: $(3)(2^7)$

This is because for any given burger, it contains one kind of meat (of $3$), and there can be from $0$ to $7$ condiments on the burger. In general, if you have $n$ objects, then the number of ways to choose any number of them is $2^n$. [1]

By the multiplication principle, the answer to this problem is $3 \cdot 2^7$.

[1] By the binomial theorem, $\sum_{x = 0}^n C(n, x)1^x 1^{n-x} = (1+1)^n = 2^n$

where $C(n, x) = \frac{n!}{(n-x)!x!}$